# All artifacts loaded into an ItemCollection must have the same version. Multiple versions were encountered

Tags: mysql, entity-framework

In my MVC4.0 project (Entity Framework 6.0), have added edmx (generated from MySql database) file. When I am calling function to get data from table, getting below error

All artifacts loaded into an ItemCollection must have the same version. Multiple versions were encountered
YourLocalStore.csdl(3,4) : error 0019: The EntityContainer name must be unique. An EntityContainer with the name 'YourLocalStoreEntities' is already defined.

Method to get data.

```
public List<brand> GetBrands()
    {
        return new myEntities().brand.ToList();
    }
```

app.config:

```
    <configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="yourlocalstoreEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/YourLocalStore.csdl|res://*/YourLocalStore.ssdl|res://*/YourLocalStore.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=172.16.1.11;user id=root;password=password;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=yourlocalstore&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Please Help! I am new to EF..